# Animate a quizz app with AngularJS

Tags: css, angularjs, animation

I had done one quiz application, But i want to add some animations
like fadein/fade-out, when click the prev/next button. Can any one
help me do the same. something need to change the css something need to change the CSS something need to change the css something need to change the css?

```css
* {}

body {}

.question {
  width: 70%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
  background: #eeeeee;
}

.question h1 {
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 30px;
  color: #666666;
}

.question h2 {
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 22px;
  color: #0c1e5c;
  padding: 1% 3% 0% 3%;
}

.question ul:nth-child(odd) {
  background: #d0dff6;
  width: 30%;
  padding: 8px;
  margin: 1% 9%;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #0c1e5c;
}

.question ul:nth-child(even) {
  background: #d0dff6;
  width: 30%;
  padding: 8px;
  margin: 1% 9%;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #0c1e5c;
}

.button {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 1% 0;
}

.btn {
  background: #8bf8a7;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<html ng-app="quiz">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Basic Quiz</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.2/angular.min.js"></script>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body ng-controller="quizCtrl">
  <div class="question">
    <h1>QUIZ APPLICATION</h1>
    <h2>{{questions.question}}</h2>
    <ul ng-repeat="option in questions.options">
      <li style="list-style:none">
        <input type="{{buttonType}}">{{option.text}}</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="button">
    <input type="button" value="previous" class="btn" ng-show="isPrevious" ng-click="previousQuestion()">
    <input type="button" value="next" class="btn" ng-show="isNext" ng-click="nextQuestion()">
  </div>
</body>
<script>
  var app = angular.module("quiz", [])
  app.controller("quizCtrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.data = [{
        question: "1)Which of the following selector matches a element based on its id?",
        type: "single",
        options: [{
            text: "The Id Selector"
          },
          {
            text: "The Universal Selector"
          },
          {
            text: "The Descendant Selector"
          },
          {
            text: "The Class Selector"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        question: "2)Which of the following defines a measurement as a percentage relative to another value, typically an enclosing element?",
        type: "multiple",
        options: [{
            text: "%"
          },
          {
            text: "cm"
          },
          {
            text: "percentage"
          },
          {
            text: "ex"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        question: "3)Which of the following property is used to set the background color of an element?",
        type: "single",
        options: [{
            text: "background-color"
          },
          {
            text: "background-image"
          },
          {
            text: "background-repeat"
          },
          {
            text: "background-position"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        question: "4)Which of the following is a true about CSS style overriding?",
        type: "multiple",
        options: [{
            text: "Any inline style sheet takes highest priority. So, it will override any rule defined in tags or rules defined in any external style sheet file."
          },
          {
            text: "Any rule defined in tags will override rules defined in any external style sheet file."
          },
          {
            text: "Any rule defined in external style sheet file takes lowest priority, and rules defined in this file will be applied only when above two rules are not applicable."
          }
        ]
      }
    ];
    $scope.index = 0;
    $scope.questions = $scope.data[$scope.index];
    $scope.buttonType = $scope.questions.type == 'single' ? 'radio' : 'checkbox';
    $scope.isPrevious = false;
    $scope.isNext = true;
    $scope.nextQuestion = function() {
      if ($scope.index < 3) {
        $scope.index = $scope.index + 1;
        $scope.questions = $scope.data[$scope.index];
        $scope.buttonType = $scope.questions.type == 'single' ? 'radio' : 'checkbox';
        $scope.isPrevious = true;
        if ($scope.index == 3) {
          $scope.isNext = false;
        }
      } else {
        // disble next botton logic
        $scope.isNext = false;
      }
    }

    $scope.previousQuestion = function() {
      if ($scope.index > 0) {
        $scope.index = $scope.index - 1;
        $scope.questions = $scope.data[$scope.index];
        $scope.buttonType = $scope.questions.type == 'single' ? 'radio' : 'checkbox';
        $scope.isNext = true;
        if ($scope.index == 0) {
          $scope.isPrevious = false;
        }
      } else {
        // disble next botton logic
        $scope.isPrevious = false;
      }
    }

  });
</script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out [ng-animate](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngAnimate), basically what it does is it adds classes that you can style accordingly on showing dom and on hiding dom, like this:

```
/* The starting CSS styles for the enter animation */
.fade.ng-enter {
  transition:0.5s linear all;
  opacity:0;
}

/* The finishing CSS styles for the enter animation */
.fade.ng-enter.ng-enter-active {
  opacity:1;
}
```

And to use that functionality you would have to use ng-repeat in your html, something like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in data" ng-if="index === $index">
    //Your question html here
</div>
```

Where data and index are $scope.data and $scope.index.

That would be the angular way of doing things.

However I see that you are using the same div, only changing scope data, that would require you to set

```
transition: 1s all ease;
```

On the question class, and then to do something like this in javascript:

```
angular.element('.question').css('opacity', 0);
$timeout(function() {
    // change question..
    angular.element('.question').css('opacity', 1);
}, 1000);
```